# can not override GetRendererForOverlay on monotouch

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkmapviewdelegate

I want to draw an overlay on top of my `MKMapView` So I defined this `delegate` class for defining the view of overlays. but as you can see it seems that from iOS 7 it is recommended that we use `GetRendererForOverlay` instead of `GetViewForOverlay`. The problem is that I can not find any method by name `GetRendererForOverlay` for override. In better word it seems that `MKMapViewDelegate` has not any virtual method for overriding `GetRendererForOverlay`. So how should we use it?

```
public class myMapDelegat : MKMapViewDelegate {


    [Obsolete ("Since iOS 7 it is recommnended that you use GetRendererForOverlay")]
    public override MKOverlayView GetViewForOverlay (MKMapView mapView, NSObject overlay)
    {
        // NOTE: Don't call the base implementation on a Model class
        // see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

}
```

I read the document that has been suggested on the NOTE but I do not find any thing about GetRendererForOverlay.

Answer (score 0):

you also can you the method `GetViewForOverlay` for iOS7. But you also need call

```
var circleOverlay = MKCircle.Circle (mapView.CenterCoordinate, 1000);
mapView.AddOverlay (circleOverlay);
```

somewhere else to fire the above method.